# LUA default value for a variable is being used when a specifc value is present

Tags: lua, default

I'm trying to use a variable in a function, and if it's not assigned use a default. In the below code, def.allowSelection is passed as false. false is printed at the print statement, but when it gets to Selection the value of allowSelection is showing true.

```
function Menu:init(def)
    self.panel = Panel(def.x, def.y, def.width, def.height)
   
    print(def.allowSelection)
    
    self.selection = Selection {
        items = def.items,
        x = def.x,
        y = def.y,
        width = def.width,
        height = def.height,
    allowSelection = def.allowSelection or true
    }
end
```

I've tried using an if statement to assign the value instead of the defualt, shown below, and it works correctly. I'm trying to figure out why the default value isn't working.

```
if def.allowSelection == false then
    self.allowSelection = false
else
    self.allowSelection = true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `false or true` evaluates to `true`. If by "default", you mean "the value that the variable should be if it's originally `nil`", then you have to check to see if it's actually `nil`. `x or defaultValue` only works if neither `nil` *or* `false` are valid values.

A single expression which does basically the same thing as your `if` statement would be: `def.allowSelection ~= false and true or false`.

Comment: Thank you. 
I was under the impression that if you used the or for assignment, it would assign the first value if it existed, but would assign the one after the or if the first variable was not set. So I thought that if def.allowSelection were false it would set allowSelection to false, but if def.allowSelection was nil it would make allowSelection be the "default" which was true.